# How do I make spiraling loop cuts around a cylinder?

Tags: modeling

How would you make these spiraling cuts around a cylinder?

[image: cylinder with spiral cuts]

Things I've already tried:

1. Simple Deform modifier with Twist. This warped the cylinder too much. I could reduce the warping somewhat by putting a bunch of horizontal loop cuts in, but it'd still warp a little bit. Pretty sure this isn't the best way - the reference image above is a perfectly straight cylinder without any warping/deformation.
2. Poke Faces. This did make some diagonal cuts, but it also generated a lot of unwanted faces in the process (and didn't give me direct control over the angle of the diagonal cuts).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm sure there are more ways of doing this,but I can think of 2 ways:

First one, with tools you already have:
**screw modifier** and **array modifier**:

[image]

Second one with addons **Add Curve: Extra Objects** and **F2** addon.
Extra objects addon allows you to to create spiral curves, and F2 addon enables you to fill in the spaces quickly

[image]
Create the spiral curve with the extra objects addon, and pres **Alt+C** to convert it to mesh, then, with the F2 addon fill in the cylinder

[image]

and in both cases you find the end of the spiral, place a cursor on it, select the rest of the loop and pres S + Z + 0

[image]

and finally, remove the double verticesyou have from the scaling