# How to model a twisted cylinder like this

Tags: modeling

I'm new to modeling. I want to make a cylinder-shape object as follow. I'm thinking of it as a twisted cylinder.

[image]

I tried using twist modifier on a cylinder but the result was disapointing.

[image]

How should I make them? I'm using Blender 2.8

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/108806/how-do-i-make-spiraling-loop-cuts-around-a-cylinder  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/114490/twisted-cylinder-hyperboloid-of-one-sheet

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would use the Screw modifier for both examples, assigned to simple profile meshes.

[image]

Because the longitudinal connections are staggered, this method avoids the creation of twisted, non-planar faces.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

For you first sketch just twist any regular n-gon with enough vertical loop-cuts (subdivisions) to support the twisting (simple deform: twist modifier):

[image]

For the second example this looks like a spiral cut into a cylinder. You can just edit the previous shape, delete every other groove and join the vertices with vertical edges (use F2 addon to do that fast), or you can:

- create a spiral with addon *Add Curve: Extra Objects*
- set bevel for the curve, set fill:Full, convert to mesh and fill the caps
- do a boolean difference

  [image]