# How to draw conical spiral column

Tags: screw-modifier

How can i draw this kind of column but with different radius on top and bottom, so the column is slightly conical.

[image]

Comment: Not sure I understand your question when you say draw, but you can use a simple deform to taper it into a cone shape.

Comment: Thank you! I'm still new to the Blender, this worked as i intended.

Comment: This obviously wouldn't be so good if you want to start bending this screw. Then you'd want to look at either a lattice or mesh deform or just using proportional editing. Good luck!

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/143274/how-to-model-a-twisted-cylinder-like-this/143278#143278 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2297/how-would-i-go-about-creating-a-spiralled-dome https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/108806/how-do-i-make-spiraling-loop-cuts-around-a-cylinder https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56396/logarithmic-curve-with-spiralling-cross-section/56398#56398 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/65633/how-can-i-create-twisted-geometry/65634#65634 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/114765/how-to-model-spiral/114771#114771